# Excel help: How to add texts/cells together

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Usually I do this Excel and it works fine:

```
= A1 & " example word"
```

However, when I do this, it doesn't work:

```
= A1 & " B1 example word"
```

So I was wondering if anyone got a solution to this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move any cell references outside the `""` and concatenate them with `&`:

```
=A1 & " " & B1 & " example word"
```

Comment: Thank you for this. If I want to add a space between A1 and B1 I just put " " right?

Is there a way around this?

Thank you for your help btw :-)

Comment: Only if you have the space at the end of the value in A1 or the beginning of the value in B1.  Otherwise excel will not automatically put it in.  But as you can see I did put the space in my formula.

Comment: @Simple Poodle: If you want a space you wold have to put this: ```& " " &``` wherever you would want the space. Don't forget the '&' (ampersand) sign.        Also don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted please.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `CONCATENATE` function:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1, " ", B1, " example word")
```